# Eclipse installer can't find JRE

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install Eclipse Oxygen on my computer. Every time I run the installer I am sent here:

http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/?vm=1_1_7_0_64_0&pn=Eclipse%20Installer&pu=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer&pi=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/128x128.png

I have installed JDK 1.8.0 in this location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the **64 bit *Eclipse Installer*** which requires a 64 bit JRE, but you only have a **32 bit JRE** (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144` means Java 8 Update 144 32 bit JDK):

- Either use the **[32 bit *Eclipse Installer*](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R/eclipse-inst-win32.exe)** or
- **[Install a 64 bit JRE or JDK](http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/?vm=1_1_7_0_64_0&pn=Eclipse%20Installer&pu=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer&pi=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/128x128.png)** or
- direct install an **[Eclipse Package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)** (as long as you have only a 32 bit JRE you have to choose the 32 bit version) without the *Eclipse Installer*.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked as soon as I updated the `PATH` environment variable to include the path to the JRE:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin
```

(Notice I am using a later Java version though.)